# Swiftkey keyboard on ios hides text input

Tags: ios, css, html

I have a simple page with a text input  at the bottom. On ios with the default keyboard selected, when the user clicks on the text input the input is pushed up and the user is able to enter text (see the first image)

[image: Text input with default keyboard]

However, when the user has the swiftkey keyboard selected the chat input is hidden as shown below.

[image: Text input is hidden when swiftkey is selected]

I'm not doing any kind of JS manipulation, all of this is plain CSS. Any idea on why this might be happening and how I could fix this?